# How to add additional shipping methods in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

How to additional shipping methods in magento ?

currently there are methods like Flat rate ,Table rates , Free shipping , UPS etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[here is a nice tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module) on how to create a shipping method.
[Or this one from Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/).

Basically you have to follow the standards presented in those tutorials and all your logic goes into the `collectRates` method of the shipping model.
There you can calculate the costs of your shipping based on the values you receive in the `$request` parameter and decide if the method is available or not and set a price to it.

Comment: thankyou , i used it , but dont know how the logic goes and calculation .

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [link](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/) also for Magento 2 tutorial on how to create custom shipping method.